# How to delete an entity from entities having same key of appengine datastore in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have entities having same key., How can I delete one of them according to the desired property?

Comment: Entities in App Engine Datastore cannot have the same key.

Comment: sorry , this may make more clear my question :
Entity p1 = Entity("Person","key1");// later set properties
Entity p2 = Entity("Person","key1");// later set properties
now how can i delete p2 from Person entity ?

Comment: If you saved p2, there is no longer p1 - it was overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a new entity with the same key as the existing entity, the existing entity gets overwritten. As a result, you always have only one entity with a given key.

For future reference, if you want to delete an entity:

```
datastore.delete(KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "key1"));
```

Comment: Then you can accept my answer to show other users that the problem is solved.